# Remove extra return from median calculation

Tags: functions, filemaker

I have a FileMaker database where I want to calculate the median value of 3 different fields. I used the code that can be found [here](https://www.briandunning.com/cf/298).

In my setup, it looks like this:

```
Let ([
beak.trait = List (beak_depthA; beak_depthB; beak_depthC);
valuelist = SortValues ( beak.trait; 1);
count = WordCount ( valueList );
odd =  MiddleValues ( valueList ; Truncate (count/2;0) +1 ; 1 ); 
even = MiddleValues ( valueList ; Truncate (count/2;0)    ; 1 )];
Case( Mod ( count ; 2 ) ; odd ; (even+ odd) / 2))
```

When there is an even number of data in the cells it generates this: 
[image]

However, when including 3 measurements, I get this: 
[image]

But if I look into the data, it's there, with an extra line return...
[image]

Would there be a way to get the value, when the number of fields is odd without the extra return?

How the code would be affected?

Answer (score 1):

Extra return might comes from SortValues function. Use [Trim4](https://www.briandunning.com/cf/166) custom function to remove it.

Trim4 ( SortValues ( beak.trait; 1) )

Use it for MiddleValues functions too.

Comment: This seems to require FileMaker pro advanced. I only have the "pro" version. Is there a way I can put this in a custom function?

Comment: What is your FileMaker version? If it is 17+, you can enable Advanced Tools in preferences. If it is 16-, you can add the entire custom function calculation to your calculation.

Comment: yeah, I have FMP 16... ok good to know

Comment: I've tried adding it to the function, but it doesn't work. How Trim4 would it be included into the function ?

Comment: Here is what I tried `Let([
beak.trait = List (beak_lengthA; beak_lengthB; beak_lengthC);
valuelist = SortValues ( beak.trait; 1);

sT = Char(9) & Char(13) & Char(32) & Char(160);
C1 = PatternCount(sT; Left(valuelist; 1));
Cn = PatternCount(sT; Right(valuelist; 1));
Ca = C1 + Cn];

count = WordCount ( If(Ca; Middle(valuelist; 1 + C1; Length(valuelist) - Ca); valuelist) );
odd =  MiddleValues ( valueList ; Truncate (count/2;0) +1 ; 1 ); 
even = MiddleValues ( valueList ; Truncate (count/2;0)    ; 1 )];
Case( Mod ( count ; 2 ) ; (odd) ; (even+ odd) / 2))`

Comment: Adding a custom function code in calculation creates a mess. You can use trial version of Advanced version and add the custom function. Once added it will work with Pro too.
You have to Trim the odd and even values.